# Finding minimum value in index(match) array [EXCEL]

Tags: arrays, excel, indexing, match, lookup

This is my simple table

```
A                           B               C
tasmania                   hobart            21
queensland                 brisbane          22
new south wales            sydney            23
northern territory         darwin            24
south australia            adelaide          25
western australia          perth             26
tasmania                   hobart            17
queensland                 brisbane          18
new south wales            sydney            19
northern territory        darwin             11
south australia           adelaide           12
western australia         perth              13
```

index match array formula:

```
=INDEX(A2:C9,MATCH(1,(H4=$A:$A)*(I4=$B:$B),0),3)
```

Basically A and B are my lookup criteria while C is the value I want to get. I want C to be the minimum value among the matched C value.

Ex. 
If I have tasmania and hobart as my criteria, I would want to get 17 because it is the minimum value and not 21.

I tried nesting `MIN` inside the index match array `(H4=$A:$A)*(I4=$B:$B)*(MIN($C:$C))` but it only results in errors

Answer (score 4):

This is rather a `MIN(IF...` than a `INDEX`. Before `SUMIF` or `COUNTIF` was implemented in `Excel` even `SUM(IF...` or `COUNT(IF...` had to be used this way.

Since there is not a `MINIFS` until now, for this we must further use:

```
{=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$1000=H4,IF($B$1:$B$1000=I4,$C$1:$C$1000,NA())))}
```

This is an array formula. Input it into the cell without the curly brackets and press [Ctrl]+[Shift]+[Enter] to confirm. The curly brackets should then appear automatically.

Comment: Since we now have MINIFS, can you update the answer using MINIFS, please?

Comment: @Vylix: Who has `MINIFS`? Only the ones who will have the newest `Excel`. And for those the [MINIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599) is pretty good documented, isn't it?

Comment: it seems I misunderstand the question, and thought this is very complicated formula. It's just MIN with 2 condition. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

With the [AGGREGATE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) as a standard formula,

```
=AGGREGATE(15, 6, C2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))/((A2:INDEX(A:A, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))=F2)*(B2:INDEX(B:B, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))=G2)), 1)
```

[image: aggregate_min]

As an older style standard formula, your original would look like,

```
=MIN(INDEX(C2:C13+((H4<>A2:A13)+(I4<>B2:B13))*1E+99, , ))
```

Comment: smart formula, but why not directly `=MIN(IF((F2=A2:INDEX(A:A,MATCH(1E+99,C:C)))*(G2=B2:INDEX(B:B,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))),C2:INDEX(C:C,MATCH(1E+99,C:C))))` as array?

Comment: Axel did array formulas in the other answer. I was sticking to non-array style.

Comment: Your furmula is also in array-style (just without CSE). The real trick should be the `C2:INDEX(C:C, MATCH(1E+99,C:C ))` which allows to use whole columns in arrays without freezing excel ;)

Comment: Yes, good point. Both of my formulas use functions in their *array style*. I should have stated CSE and non-CSE.