# Finding key for minimum value and conditions in excel

Tags: arrays, excel

This is my table (copied from the similar question  [Finding minimum value in index(match) array [EXCEL]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36953520/finding-minimum-value-in-indexmatch-array-excel))

```
A                           B    C    D
tasmania                    10   3    10
queensland                  22   8    10
new south wales             10   12   12
northern territory           8   4    15
south australia             12   2    8
western australia           32   4    15
tasmania                    72   6    16
```

I have criteria for B and C, and I want to retrieve the A with the lowest corresponding value D. Values in B, C and D can be duplicates, values in A can not.

Example:

```
B >= 8
C >= 4
```

Should result in "queensland" (lowest matching value is 10), but not "tasmania" (has the same cost)

I am currently trying this array formula:

```
{ =MIN(IF(B:B>=8;IF(C:C>=4;D;""));1) }
```

Which returns the correct lowest D, but since I am losing the informaiton about A, I can not retrieve the value for A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This as an array formula should work for you:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH(MIN(IF($B$1:$B$7>=8,IF($C$1:$C$7>=4,$D$1:$D$7))),IF($B$1:$B$7>=8,IF($C$1:$C$7>=4,$D$1:$D$7)),0))
```

It should be noted that if you have Excel 2016 or Office365, you'll have access to the [MINIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599) which is probably better suited for this task (i don't actually have the newest version, so am unable to test)

Comment: This solution seems to work just perfect! Also, thanks for pointing out MINIFS to me!